# Repeated querying in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com for my back end.I am making an app which needs to check for a table value repeatedly in the background.I have already created the Android service.Is there any other or direct way than an infinite loop to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the only way with Parse is with a loop. You will have to structure it strange though where Parse methods are `async` tasks.